# Auto leading space between two elements in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uistoryboard

I have 3 hidden Labels, after a check from database i set `label.isHidden = false` only if the value of that label exists.

This is the situation when all labels have right value[image]

So I'm using Storyboard with AutoLayout for determinate the position of these labels but i need to pull labels to left if one of these still hidden keeping the space with other labels.

This is how looking now[image]

Is it possible to do it programmatically? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **StackView** for this. You don't have to do tiring auto-layout if you use StackView.Rather you will find what you want

[image]
[image]

After clicking hide.

[image]

After clicking show

[image]

Comment: Is possible to use a StackView into a CollectionViewCell?

Comment: But how to reproduce the same label positions?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to align each label relative to the adjacent label (label1.trailing to label2.leading for example).

Then instead of setting any label to hidden you can set the width constraint to 0 and call `layoutIfNeeded` on the superview, all other labels will then layout accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use StackView to handle this Space instead of using isHidden to hide the label.

You can also achive that by AutoLayout, use yourConstraint.constant = 0 or priority property of the constraints.